# Angular 2 - DTO's & models

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Trying to understand the better approach to DTO's and/or Models in Angular 2.

For example, I'm making an api call and typing the response to Items array like this:

```
get list(): Observable<Items[]> {
    return this.http.get('/items')
}
```

I assume this is good enough. But, I've seen others create new objects from the returned api data.
For example:

```
get list(): Observable<Items[]> {
    return this.http
        .get('/items')
        .map(items => {
                let newArray = [];
                items.forEach(item => {
                    newArray.push(new item(item.prop1, item.prop2))
                })
                return newArray;
            }
        )
}
```

Unless I am going to augment or modify the properties at runtime, I don't know that this is necessary to create a bunch of new objects? This may be a rudimentary question, but what is the recommended approach and why?

Comment: Imo it doesn't make any sense in this example. It rather produces a lot of overhead in your api calls.